# Ejecutar navegador en pantalla completa al iniciar S.O Linux

Tags: html, css, linux, raspberry-pi, navegador-web

Estoy realizando un *proyecto Domotico* en el que tengo los siguientes componentes:

- RaspberryPi + Relés para accionar luces.
- Pantalla TouchScreen 15**

La interfaz y back-end lo hice todo en ambiente web `(HTML + CSS + NODEJS + SOCKET.IO)`, pero necesito hacer que al inciar el `Raspberry` ejecute el navegador en una dirección web predefinida y en pantalla completa.

Saludos.

Comment: Deberías añadir que SO estás usando y qué navegador quieres que se lance, pero asumiendo que usas Raspbian, tienes que editar el fichero `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` y añadir ahí la aplicación a lanzar al iniciar la sesión

Comment: Excelente respuesta @Pablo Lozano

Comment: https://norfipc.com/internet/navegador-google-chrome-trucos.html